# Death in the Dungeon

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking, situation

You are located in a dark dungeon that has only one hole to the outside, so that air can be let in so you won’t die from suffocation.

This suits you just fine, as you were a former secret agent and have been subject to much harsher conditions.

An analysis of what is in the dungeon:

> Cement walls, a bowling ball that can only be cracked that is glued fast to the ground, your wishlist from two years ago with
>   the word hammer at the top. A mirror. A salt-shaker. And a pepper-shaker that only
>   works if you reverse a superstition. A
>   magical escape pad that works if you bombard it with tiny black particles.

One day, a gigantic guard comes into the room, shoves you aside and pushes a wad of fast-cementing glue into your life-hole (pun not intended). 
He leaves and slams the air-tight door shut and locks it.

How do you survive?

*Note: There are many puns and play-on-words so don't think too literally*

Comment: Reminds me of the "you have a mirror and a table in the dungeon" riddle.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie Isn't it "hammer"?

Comment: And....here comes the lateral-thinking tag...sighhhh

Comment: From the way you commented on the existing answers, it seems like you're looking for a _very specific_ answer to a _very_ broad lateral-thinking scenario...

Comment: I get that you've probably got a list of puns/wordplay to get you to use all items available, but surely you can just start directly at @NL628's step 4. I'm pretty sure most people would be able to get to that step with simple brute force (either with their bare hands, or using one of the other objects as a blunt instrument).

Comment: (which is to say, I share @Votbear's concern)

Comment: As Alconja said. By nature of broad questions, there will possibly be multiple valid answers, like what @NL628 submitted. Simply saying "nah you're wrong" isn't exactly fair when the answer is completely valid given the limited information you've provided imo.

Comment: If you want people to come into the answer you thought of, imo it's your responsibility as the puzzle-maker to give the extra specifications required, or hint to what parts of the solution are wrong / not good enough yet. Give a valid reason why the answer is not correct and guide it to the correct one - Saying "No, it's not 100% correct" just because _you_ think it isn't right, based only on information private to you, isn't very fair is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Maybe Answer?

Step 1:

> Look into the mirror and see what you saw. Take out the saw. Hint gotten from [here](https://riddlesbrainteasers.com/room-windows/).

Okay so far I'm pretty sure this is good...the next step is a little...uh...far-fetched.

Step 2:

> Carve an illuminati symbol on the mirror using a saw :D

Step 3:

> Throw the bowling ball at the mirror and crack it.

Step 4:

> Cracking a mirror is bad luck, so to reverse it, toss some salt behind your back. Gotten [here](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-1385380/Why-throw-salt-shoulder-superstitions-answered.html).

Step 5:

> Get the pepper and pepper/bombard the magic escape pad.

Step 6:

> Escape the room.

I managed to use all the materials in the room LOL. Thanks @QuantumTwinkie for some ideas.

Comment: Not 100% correct yet

Comment: I give up lolol

Answer (score 3):

Step 1.

> Grab the magical escape pad and shake the pepper(behind your back to reverse the superstition of throwing salt) on it.

Step 2.

> This would bombard it(with little black particles), in order to make the escape pad work.

Step 3.

> Then you would make a wish to escape.

I know this does not include all of the other supplies listed but it might work due to simplicity.

Comment: I apologize I forgot to make some things clearer.

Comment: You cannot get the pepper out without reversing a superstition, and the particles must be black.

Comment: This is not correct. What is the superstition?

Comment: Look at your wish-list in the mirror, then use the mirror-hammer to crack the bowling ball?  (Cracking a mirror is bad luck, but using the mirror to crack something else is reversing it?)